# How to parameterise externally saved sql query in karate-dsl

Tags: karate

I have a situation where I need to use DB and I am storing qll queries externally as .txt. I want to execute these queries with different iterations hence I am using a Scenario outline.

I would like to know what is the better way to achieve this. Currently, I am using the below code but need to repeat replace code for all the parameters.

```
SELECT REWARDS_POINTS
FROM ABC Table
WHERE IS_ACTIVE = <active>
AND DISCOUNT_TYPE = <discount>
AND PRODUCT_TYPE = <product>




Scenario Outline: sample
    * def query = read("classpath:priceQuery.txt")
    * replace query.active = <active>
    * replace query.discount = <discount>
    * replace query.product = <product>
    * print 'query is > ', query
    Examples:
      |discount|active|product|
      |   5     |1|toy|
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine as it is. You can also do this, refer docs:  https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace

```
* replace query
| token    | value    |
| active   | active   |
| discount | discount |
| product  | product  |
```

But please note that `replace` is just a convenience built-in to Karate. You can easily write a JS or Java utility and use it. So assuming you have defined a re-usable function called `prepare()` which can retrieve variables e.g. using `karate.get()` and even update using `karate.set()` you can end up with this:

```
* def query = prepare('classpath:priceQuery.txt')
```

There are many options. It is up to your knowledge of Karate and some creativity.